# CakePHP: Customized error message should display on the same page instead of moving some other page

Tags: php, cakephp, error-handling

In cakephp, I have created customized page for error 4xx and 5xx. It is working properly too. When error is happening, it is navigate to another page plain page of same url along with Error message(please find the image here)

[image: )]

What I need is, if error happens means, it should not navigate to that plain page. The error message should display on the same page. Have tried to display some Flash messages but not works!

Here the files that I have created
error/error400.ctp
error/error500.ctp
layout/error.ctp

Please help me out to attain this!

Comment: Did you get the problem solved?

Comment: Thanks for response :). But my problem is not get solved. No. The thing is, I have to display the error on my UI page itself. but in my case it is moving to some blank page with message that i have hard-coded in error.ctp.

Comment: For example: Assuming that, I am trying to login, some internal error is happening means it redirects to the page that I attached above. But what i need is... some message or Flash message (customized message) should display on that login UI page itself.

Comment: <body>
    <div id="container">
        <div id="header">
            <h1><?= __('Error') ?></h1>
        </div>
        <div id="content">
            <?= $this->Flash->render() ?>
            
            <?= $this->fetch('content') ?>
        </div>
        <div id="footer">
            <?= $this->Html->link(__('Back'), 'javascript:history.back()') ?>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/144411/discussion-between-aipd-tech-and-janani-k).

Answer (score 0):

Just put the debug mode off

`Configure::write("debug",0)`

**Edit**

If you want to show custom error page then do this

```
function beforeRender () {
    if ($this->name == 'CakeError') { 
        $this->layout = 'error';
    }
}
```

and if you just want to show message on the page itself, Use Flash messages

Comment: @JananiK Did it helped?

Comment: No. Still it remains same :) Flash message is not working.

Comment: @JananiK Let us [continue this discussion in chat.](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/144411/discussion-between-aipd-tech-and-janani-k)